# form_open helper function not working

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I use of CodeIgniter. I have a form that saved in formregister.php.
I've written in first of the form formregister.php:
`echo form_open('main/sabtm');`
The 'main' is a controller and 'sabtm' is a function in controller.
Also, I set `$this->load->helper('form');` in  controller.
Then,  when I click on button in the form, the url in browser changed to `localhost/emdad/index.php/formregister`, where in source code of my page has set `<form action="localhost/emdad/index.php/main/sabtm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">`

what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a strange problem. If I have form action `"localhost/emdad/index.php/main/sabtm"` in my source code and by submitting the form it changes to `"localhost/emdad/index.php/formregister"`. I think following points can be checked for such an issue:

1. Please check if you have controller `"formregister.php"` and somewhere in form/web page you are changing the form action via some client side script like javascript.
2. Please check if you have properly closed the form `(form_close())`.
3. Please check the method `sabtm()` if it has some validations and it redirects to respective page upon success/failure of the validation.

Alternatively please post full code of controller & view.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I have tried to provide possible scenarios for respective information provided for the problem. What else I can put here in absence of full code. Any suggestion for answering this question is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your post looks like generic debugging advice and a request for more information. It doesn't seem to try to answer the question. In may very well be that this question isn't answerable without more information, but comments are the place to ask for it. I should however point out that I'm apparently in the minority in thinking your post isn't an answer, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable advice. I'll keep in mind this point and actually I don't have enough reputation to comment on the question that's why I mentioned it in my post.

Answer (score 0):

the file App.php of the folder Config change

```
public $indexPage = 'index.php';
```

to

```
public $indexPage = '';
```